# Delay to establish network connection

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

I'm running Windows 10 (Version 10.0.16299 Build 16299) on my Dell Latitude E7450.

Once my laptop is powered from sleep, lid is raised it takes like 1 minute to establish connection (doesn't matter whether it's wireless or Ethernet).

I'm looking for help in order to get rid of this annoying delay. If there's any information I have to provide - let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Enable "**Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power**" for wireless and wired network adapter.

Since with it Windows puts the network card to sleep and when it resumes it puts it back to D0. But Windows completely halts the device and on resume reinitializes it when it unchecked.

Besides that, also update both of network adapter drivers and Windows version to latest Windows 10 16299.334.

Comment: That option is enabled. I'll try updating Windows to latest version as well  because my drivers are up to date.